# How to fix Error injecting: io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gatling

I am trying to run a **gatling** project using **Maven** from **Git** in **Jenkins** and getting the following error:

```
[INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:2.2.0:execute (default-cli) @ gatling-training ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:122)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:464)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/gatling/mojo/GatlingMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
    ... 52 more
```

Can anybody shed some light on the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem using **jdk 8** in Jenkins.

That was what caused the problem.

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had this "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/gatling/mojo/GatlingMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" issue when there was different version of java(1.8) and javac(1.7) installed in my system.

Check your java and javac -version

I solved my issue by running yum install:
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64